# Price Rules in Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq, pricebook, pricing, cpq-plugins, pricerule

I am trying to learn Salesforce CPQ Price rules. I am trying to create something like the following: If the Add on product added is more than 10 then the primary product quote line will have an Additional Discount of 10%

So I have added the Price Conditions accordingly

1. If Quote Line product is 'Add On'
2. If Quote Line quantity is greater than 10.

Now my issue is that when I am trying to create Price Actions, I add the Target Object as 'Quote Line', Target Field as 'Additional Discount' and value as 10. My problem here is that the discount is coming up on the Add On product instead of Primary Product. I am not sure how to fix the issue or if its actually possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Price rules act on the records that meet the criteria. In this case, you might need to make a summary variable that summarizes how many add-ons have been purchased. Then you can use that summary variable to determine whether or not to update the primary product.